# Enlarge system to be basis

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $\{x_1,x_2\}$ vector system. The task wants from me to extend it to make basis of $V_4$.

$x_1$ = $(1,1,0,1)$ and 
$x_2$ = $(2,1,1,1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general method we can find two orthogonal vectors solving

- $(a,b,c,d) \cdot x_1=a+b+d=0$
- $(a,b,c,d) \cdot x_2=2a+b+c+d=0$

from here we obtain a solution with to free parameters $(s,t)$ and then

- $(s,t)=(1,0)\to x_3$
- $(s,t)=(0,1)\to x_4$

and since those are orthogonal to $x_1$ and $x_2$ they are linearly independent and form a basis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add two more  linearly independent vectors  to $(1,1,0,1),(2,1,1,1).$

You have many choices, for example $(1,0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,0,1)$ will do.

To check linear independence you find the determinant of the matrix $$ M = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&1\\2&1&1&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

which is  $1 \ne 0$

In general you find orthogonal vectors by solving a system of equations.

You want the dot product of the unknown vector with the known vectors  to be $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any algorithm with the help of which I can fill missing vectors, by not guessing. And is there any way of checking that the new two vectors with the given ones create a basis. Thanks.

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani How can we compute cross product of 4 demension vectors? Is it exist at all? Here is an article, where author formulates that cross product doesnt exist in demensions between 3 and 7. http://www.jstor.org/stable/2323537?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Thanks,  you are correct. I forgot what dimension I  was talking about.

Comment: While this works for the problem at hand, would you try and guess when you have to complete a set of 200 vectors to a basis of a 500-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Then you have to solve a system to find a  new vector which is orthogonal to the given vectors and repeat the process until you are done.